# Is there a way to request my xcode files from Apple

Tags: app-store

So... I have a few apps that Iv'e published on the AppStore a few years ago, and unfortunately I did a mistake and erased their files from my mac without any backup..

Is there any way to ask Apple for the files of those apps? Haven't found any source of information online.

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for Apple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: @JJJ You can say it on any question. those files are important to me and I would like to know if anybody struggled with this issue aswel

Comment: No, I can only say it on customer support questions.

Comment: Apple does not have the Xcode project files or source code files for the apps you published in the App store.